# Two OneDrive accounts?

Tags: onedrive, nokia-lumia-1020

Is it possible to have two OneDrive accounts on the Windows Phone?

I have a Lumia 1020 and haven't been able to figure it out thus far. I have a OneDrive for work and home and would like to access both. Right now I head into IE and then log into my work one when needed.

Comment: Do you have the latest version of the OneDrive app? It was recently updated to support OneDrive for Business as well (assuming that's what you use for work).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The OneDrive app supports a personal OneDrive (tied to the primary account used when setting the phone up) and also you can connect to a "OneDrive for Business" account - simply tap the three horizontal lines near the top left of the app, and then tap on **Add OneDrive for Business** and sign in with the identity you connect to your work OneDrive.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [Woopiti](https://www.windowsphone.com/s?appid=20e820bf-56a3-4ec5-a839-3cb2886c64b6). It is an application for multiple cloud storages such as Dropbox, Google Drive and OneDrive (and some other cloud storages too). You should be able to register both OneDrive accounts within this app.

If you cannot do this, use one OneDrive client per OneDrive account, just like the official OneDrive app and Woopiti, for example.